# do partial data with the TukeyHSD

Tags: r, anova

When doing a big ANOVA, sometimes we need to work with the Tukey HSD test to verify the pair significance. Since it is a time-consuming task, would like to ask for advice that How I can do partial test. I mean, I'd known the significant item after summary(aov), and I only want to do Tukey HSD on the major ones, and get rid of the rest. Here is the reference code:

```
seed(100)
# create the DF for aov
X <- rep(letters[1:3],each=6)
Y <- rep(sample(100,3),each=6)
Z <- rep(rep(LETTERS[3:4],9))
m <- data.frame(X,Y,Z)

# do aov and summary
fit <- aov(Y~X+Z, data=m)

summary(fit)

#             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq   F value Pr(>F)    
# X            2   7756    3878 1.329e+30 <2e-16 ***
# Z            1      0       0 7.260e-01  0.409    
# Residuals   14      0       0                     
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

TukeyHSD(fit)
#  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
#    95% family-wise confidence level

# Fit: aov(formula = Y ~ X + Z, data = m)

# $`X`
#     diff lwr upr p adj
# b-a    4   4   4     0
# c-a   -1  -1  -1     0
# c-b   -5  -5  -5     0

# $Z
#           diff           lwr          upr     p adj
# D-C          0 -2.363621e-15 2.363621e-15         1
```

Can I just do X, not Z? something like `TukeyHSD(fit[["X"]])`?

btw, why there is `$'X'`, but not for $Z? Many Thanks.